# Scrapy: Set conditional settings.py

Tags: python, scrapy, settings, conditional-statements

I'd like to apply specific settings and download_middlewares (proxies) only if a file exists. The spider should run with proxies only if the .txt with the proxies list exists, otherwise, it should run without proxies, with the default IP and port.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work for me:

*settings.py*

```
import os.path

if os.path.isfile("../proxies.txt"):

     BOT_NAME = 'whatever'
     SPIDER_MODULES = ['whatever.spiders']
     NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'whatever.spiders'
     RETRY_ENABLED = False
     REDIRECT_ENABLED = False
     DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 15
     COOKIES_ENABLED = False
     LOG_ENABLED = True

    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'whatever.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100
    }

else:
   BOT_NAME = 'whatever'
   SPIDER_MODULES = ['whatever.spiders']
   NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'whatever.spiders'

   DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {

    }
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you listing should. Is there anything error in other code snippet?

Comment: You are right! The problem didn't come from there. Thanks!